# periodicity of constant discrete time signals

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic

are constant discrete time signals periodic?
example \begin{equation}
e^{i10\pi n}
\end{equation}
my proffesor says that this signal is aperiodic, in the discrete sense. but it seems wrong, because 
unlike in the continuous case, i can calculate the smallest time period , which is 1.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  As you say, $e^{\imath 10 \pi n}$ at integer $n$ is a constant. Are constants periodic? [See this question and answer on SE.math.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385273/is-a-constant-function-periodic)

Comment: @PeterK. Since this is a discrete signal, I'd say it is periodic with period 1, as abhishek suspects. http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/Fundamental_Frequency/node2.html

Comment: @MBaz Yes, [it looks like you're correct](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iii-fourier-series-and-laplace-transform/fourier-series-basics/MIT18_03SCF11_s21_1text.pdf), it just doesn't have a fundamental or minimal period.

Comment: @PeterK. the document you gave a reference to says that a constant continuous time signal has no fundamental or minimal period. The document says nothing about a constant discrete time signal.

Comment: @abhishek Surely that’s true in discrete time too? If the fundamental period must be greater than zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally, "$n$" is the symbol we use here for discrete-time.  if your professor said that:

$$\begin{align}
x[n] &= e^{i10 \pi n} \\
 &= e^{i 2 \pi (5n)} \\
\end{align}$$

is not periodic with a period of $1$ (assuming $n \in \mathbb{Z}$) or a period of $\frac15$ (assuming $n \in \mathbb{R}$), then your professor is mistaken.

Comment: More generally, if the frequency is a rational multiple of $pi$, then the sequence is periodic. $10pi$ is a rational multiple of $pi$.